# Suitability of one-way repeated measures MANOVA

Tags: repeated-measures, econometrics, manova, mancova

I'm undertaking a research study where I want to look at the difference between the value of a variable before and after an intervention. I've been suggested the one-way repeated measures MANOVA approach. From what I've read about this approach online, you look at data from two different populations to incorporate as independent variables. The problem I'm facing is that I don't have a control group (due to some ethical considerations). Rather, my survey includes some questions that act as a control. As a result, all my sampling units come from the same population as such, and the independent variables I am looking at are demographic factors like age, education, gender, political affiliation, etc.

Is a one-way repeated measures MANOVA with dependent variables as the pre and post intervention scores and the demographic features as independent variables suitable here?